# How to set minimum of the yaxis in jQplot outside the properties

Tags: javascript, jqplot

Hello I need to set maximum/minimum of the yaxis. I can do it in the properties:

```
var s1 = [5, 3, 7, 1];
plot1 = $.jqplot(divik, [s1], {
seriesDefaults:{
  renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
},
axes: {

  yaxis: {
    padMin: 1.1,
    min:0
  }
},
```

});

but when I tried to change it, my try didn't work:

```
plot1.axes.yaxis.min=-100;
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the [replot method](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.replot) after changing the properties. Something like this:

```
    plot1.axes.yaxis.min=-2;
    plot1.replot();
```

JSFiddle version:

http://jsfiddle.net/38UX3/1/